# Vuex update state by using store actions

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have two functions in my store, one that gets data by calling API and one that toggles change on cell "approved". Everything working fine, except that when I toggle this change it happens in database and I get the response that it is done but It doesn't update on UI.

I am confused, what should I do after toggling change to reflect change on UI, should I call my API from .then or should I call action method responsible for getting data from server.

```
export default {
  state: {
    drivers: {
      allDrivers:[],
      driversError:null
    },
    isLoading: false,
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    driverApproved: null,
    driverNotApproved: null
  },
  getters: {
    driversAreLoading (state) {
      return state.isLoading;
    },
    driverError (state) {
      return state.drivers.driversError;
    },
    getAllDrivers(state){
      return state.drivers.allDrivers
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    getAllDrivers (state) {
      state.isLoading=true;
      state.drivers.driversError=null;
    },
    allDriversAvailable(state,payload){
      state.isLoading=false;
      state.drivers.allDrivers=payload;
    },
    allDriversNotAvailable(state,payload){
      state.isLoading=false;
      state.drivers.driversError=payload;
    },
    toggleDriverApproval(state){
      state.isLoading = true;
    },
    driverApprovalCompleted(state){
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.driverApproved = true;
    },
    driverApprovalError(state){
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.driverError = true;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    allDrivers (context) {
      context.commit("getAllDrivers")
      return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
        http.get('/api/admin/getAllDrivers').then(
          response=>{
            if (response.data.success){
              let data=response.data.data;
                data=data.map(function (driver) {
                return {
                  /* response */
                };
              });
              context.commit("allDriversAvailable",data);
              res();
            }else {
              context.commit("allDriversNotAvailable",response.data)
              rej()
            }
          })
          .catch(error=>{
            context.commit("allDriversNotAvailable",error.data)
            rej()
          });
      });
    },
    toggleDriverApproval (context, payload){
      return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
        http.post("/api/admin/toggleDriverApproval",{
          driver_id: payload
        })
        .then( response => {
          context.commit('driverApprovalCompleted');
          res();
        }).catch( error =>{
          context.commit('driverApprovalError');
          rej()
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the code on the view, I wrote the necessary code for better clarification of the problem

```
export default {
  name: 'Drivers',
  data: () => ({
    data: [],
    allDrivers: [],
    driversErrors: []
  }),
  created() {
    this.$store
      .dispatch('allDrivers')
      .then(() => {
        this.data = this.$store.getters.getAllDrivers
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.errors = this.$store.getters.driverError
      })
  },
  computed: {
    isLoading() {
      return this.$store.getters.driversAreLoading
    }
  },
  methods: {
    verify: function(row) {
      console.log(row)
      this.$store.dispatch('toggleDriverApproval', row.id).then(() => {
        this.data = this.$store.getters.getAllDrivers
        console.log('done dis')
      })
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Are your mutations called? Is the state changed?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your issue, you want the UI displaying your data to change to the updated data after making a post request.

If you are using Vuex you will want to commit a mutation, and use a getter display the data.

I am not sure how your post request is being handled on the server but if successful typically you would send a response back to your front end with the updated data, and commit a mutation with the updated data.

Example:

Make a Post request

```
toggleDriverApproval (context, payload){
  return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
   http.post("/api/admin/toggleDriverApproval",{
       driver_id: payload
   })
   .then( response => {
   context.commit('driverApprovalCompleted', response.data);
   res();
   }).catch( error =>{
      context.commit('driverApprovalError', error.response.data);
      rej()
     })
   })
 }
```

If succesful commit the mutation

```
.then( response => {
 context.commit('driverApprovalCompleted', response.data);
 res();
})
```

`response.data` being your data you want to mutate the state with.

Mutation Example:

```
customMutation(state, data) {
    state.driverApproval = data
}
```

Getter Example:

```
driver(state) {
   return state.driverApproval
}
```

displaying the getter in a template

```
 <template>
  <div v-if="driver">{{driver}}</div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: Example,
  computed: {
    driver() {
      return this.$store.getters.driver
    },
    // or use mapGetters
    ...mapGetters(['driver'])
  }
}
</script>
```

more examples can be found at [Vuex Docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/)